# is there a way i can fix my api request issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I did this but the (endPointUrl) after await get, is showing error, and having being have lot of issue, in which any url I use never responds always showing failed to locate localhost

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and create a [mre]; then, [edit] your question.

Comment: Hi, Ayorinde Michael I think you might have accidentally forgotten to add the code in your question.